# Sign transaction using truffle-contract

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract

Is it possible to call contract methods protected with modifier like `onlyOwner` without access to the node with the keyfile **using only private key**? I know that I can create raw transaction and sign it using `ethereumjs-tx` but when I need to execute chain of 4-5 transaction it becomes boring. I'd like to use truffle-contract infrastructure.

Comment: I've used [Truffle HDWallet provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider), but it uses a seed instead of the private key. Under the hood it uses [MetaMask's Web3 provider engine](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine), so it should be possible to implement a custom provider that accepts a raw private key.